# DeMigrate from .net 5 back to 3.5

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm trying to DeMigrate the following code from 5 to 3.5 and getting this error:

> CS1513: Line 203: } expected

the error if referencing the second curly brace of this part

```
catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                //DClient.Error(ex); }
```

of the below method and i can't figure out why it's giving this message. it's not already in a sln for VS and i'm honestly not sure how to do that or if that would even give me the proper "suggested fix" i would need to fix this

```
public void Invoke(MessageCreateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e == null ||
                    !e.Message.Content[0].Equals(CommandPrefix))
                    return;

                List<string> parameters = Split(e.Message.Content);

                if (parameters == null)
                    parameters = new List<string>();

                string command;
                if (parameters.Count == 0)
                    command = e.Message.Content;
                else
                    command = parameters[0];

                command = command.TrimStart(CommandPrefix);

                AccessLevel access = DClient.UserManager.GetAccessLevel(e.Author.Id);

                //Return when command channel is set, we are outside of it and have accesslevel vip or lower
                //Return when we cannot find the command itself
                //Return when the command is disabled
                if ((e.Guild != null && access <= AccessLevel.VIP && DClient.Settings.CommandChannelId != 0 && DClient.Settings.CommandChannelId != e.Channel.Id) ||
                    !_commands.TryGetValue(command.ToLower(), out ICommand cmd))
                    return;
                else if (cmd.IsDisabled)
                {
                    e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Command is currently disabled");
                    return;
                }

                switch (cmd.CommandType)
                {
                    case CommandType.None:
                        break;

                    case CommandType.Private:
                        if (e.Guild != null)
                        {
                            e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You can only use this command in a private chat!");
                            return;
                        }
                        break;

                    case CommandType.Public:
                        if (e.Guild == null)
                        {
                            e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You can only use this command in a server chat!");
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                if (access < cmd.AccessLevel)
                {
                    e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("You do not have enough permissions to use this command");
                    return;
                }

                if (parameters.Count > 0)
                    parameters.RemoveAt(0);

                if (cmd.MinParameters > 0 && parameters.Count < cmd.MinParameters)
                {
                    e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Not enough parameters");
                    return;
                }

                string afterCmd = e.Message.Content;

                if (afterCmd.Length > cmd.Command.Length + 1)
                    afterCmd = afterCmd.Remove(0, cmd.Command.Length + 2);
                else
                    afterCmd = string.Empty;

                DiscordMember member = null;
                if (e.Guild != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        member = e.Guild.GetMemberAsync(e.Author.Id).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }
                    catch (AggregateException ex)
                    {
                        if (!ex.InnerExceptions.Any(t => t is NotFoundException))
                            throw;
                    }
                }

                CommandEventArgs arg = new CommandEventArgs(e.Guild, e.Channel, e.Author, member,
                                                            e.Message, access, parameters, afterCmd);

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( new WaitCallback( SendCallback ), arg );

                /* ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Invoke(this, arg);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (ex is UnauthorizedException)
                        {
                            e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Internal Error: Unauthorized (This error can happen when the bot tries to send a message to someone via DM but the user has disabled DMs from non friends)");
                            return;
                        }

                        if (Debug)
                            e.Channel.SendMessageAsync(GetDebugExceptionMessage(ex));
                        else
                            e.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Something went wrong executing this command");
                    }
                })); */

            }
            catch //(Exception ex)
            {
                //DClient.Error(ex);
            }

            string GetDebugExceptionMessage(Exception ex)
            {
                return ("Something went wrong executing this command (L: {0} At: {1}.{2}: {3})", GetLineNumber(ex), (ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType?.FullName ?? "unkown", ex.TargetSite.Name, ex.Message, ));
            }
        }
```

Comment: `GetDebugExceptionMessage` looks like a local function, which is a feature of c# 7.0.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I didn't expect that error to be thrown in that situation

Comment: Are you really migrating from .NET (Core) 5 to .NET *Framework* 3.5? If so, why not at least migrate to something released within the last 20 years (.NET Framework 3.5 was released February of 2002, over 20 years ago)

Comment: In this case, what followed looks like a method signature, but you can't have one of those inside a method (pre c#7), so maybe you missed a `}`? Building a "[something] expected" error into a compiler is a hard problem, as it's essentially just trying to guess what might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Lakeman's answer solved it

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Instead of posting a new question to explain that another question worked, I highly recommend clicking the checkmark on Jeremy Lakeman's post to mark it as the answer, and/or comment on  jeremy's answer that it worked